# How to manipulate RGB levels in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a image in RGB that looks something like this:

[image]

I'd like to change the blue levels (preferably make them brighter/white) to get something like:

[image]

I have following loop that goes through all the pixels of my image

```
 for( int y = 0; y < result_cropped.rows; y++ ){

   Vec3b* result_cropped_row = result_cropped.ptr<Vec3b>(y);
   for( int x = 0; x < result_cropped.cols; x++ ){
       //...manipulate levels
   }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: if you want to access/manipulate each single pixel (e.g. independantly), try `Vec3b & currentPixel = result_cropped_row[x]; currentPixel[0] = ... /*B channel*/; currentPixel[1] = ... /*G channel*/; currentPixel[2] = ... /*R channel*/;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in most cases, you should avoid writing loops (slow, error prone)

you could do it as simple as:

```
img += Scalar(40,0,0); // b,g,r
```

Comment: oh wow, i didn't think it was going to be that easy. thanks a ton!

Comment: berak I like your solution, but I disagree that isADon's loop is slow.